# Alert box needed in js to work properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a form where you fill and when you click the submit button a js script is called which by it's turn call a php script to get results and displays them in the user in the form of an alert box.

The weird thing is that if i have the command "alert("msg")" in my js( you can see it below) evertyhing works great but if i remove it nothing seems to work....any idea why is this happening?
Thnx

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 <label for="userFirstName">Name </label>
 <input name="userFirstName" id="userFirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"        autofocus  /><br>
 <label for="userLastName">Surname </label>
 <input name="userLastName" id="userLastName" type="text" placeholder="Surname"  /><br>
 <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
  <input name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Your Telephone  Number(10 digits))"  /><br>
 <label for="email">Email Address</label>
 <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address"  /><br>
 <button class="clearbutton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkInput(userFirstName.value,userLastName.value,phonenumber.value,email.value)">Add Partner</button>
```

The js script

```
//the first is the file and the second the value
function checkInput(name,surname,tel,email) {
//alert(name+" "+surname+" "+tel+" "+email);    
xmlhttpURL=GetXmlHttpObjectURL();
if (xmlhttpURL==null) {
    alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
}

var url = "AddPartnersDb.php";
url = url + "?n=" + name + "&l=" + surname + "&t=" + tel + "&m=" + email;                           
    // Adds a parameter (q) to the URL with the content of the drop-down box
url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();                    
    // Adds a random number to prevent the server from using a cached file
xmlhttpURL.onload = stateChanged;   // Each time the readyState property changes, the stateChanged() function will be executed
xmlhttpURL.open("GET",url,true);                // Opens the XMLHTTP object with the given URL
xmlhttpURL.send(null); 
alert("msg"); //<---------------------When i have this everything sees ok...
    } 

function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttpURL.readyState==4) {
        var res = xmlhttpURL.responseText;      
        //if(res.length>0)
            alert(res);
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObjectURL() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
```

the php script:

```
<?php

//database connection
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','WTHw3') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//the values sent from the ajax script
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_GET["n"]));
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_GET["l"]));
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_GET["m"]));;
$tel=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_GET["t"]));

//a var to store the result(if any) and show the error to the admin
$result="";
if ( !eregi ( '[a-z||0-9]@[a-z||0-9].[a-z]', $email ) ) { //checks to make sure the email address is in a valid format  
    $result .= "Not Valid e-mail!\n";
}   

if(strlen($tel) != 10){
    $result .= "Telephone must be a numeric with 10 nums length!";
}elseif(!is_numeric($tel)) {        
    $result .= "Telephone must be a numeric with 10 nums length!!!";
    }

//check for a validation error
if($result==""){
    //query to be executed
    //$query = "INSERT INTO  Partners(partnerName,partnerSurname,partnerTel,partnerEmail) values  ('$name','$surname','$tel','$email')"; 
    //query execution
    //$dbResult = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database.');
    echo "wtf";

}else {
    echo $result;
}
//close connection
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using a library like jquery?

Comment: Totally agree with @RobApodaca, if it is more than a small project you should consider using a javascript library (jQuery is great!). And also take a look at your email validation code: "nick.name@yahoo.com.es" and "me+tag@gmail.com" are valid email addresses too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your button shouldn't be type "submit", since you are calling a webservice via AJAX when user clicks: when the alert() is called it gives time for the ajax call to be completed before submitting the form.

Try changing the type of your submit button to `button`, and add a `return false` and the end of `checkInput()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want button type as submit, you can write code like

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return checkInput(userFirstName.value,userLastName.value,phonenumber.value,email.value)">
 <label for="userFirstName">Name </label>
 <input name="userFirstName" id="userFirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"        autofocus  /><br>
 <label for="userLastName">Surname </label>
 <input name="userLastName" id="userLastName" type="text" placeholder="Surname"  /><br>
 <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
  <input name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Your Telephone  Number(10 digits))"  /><br>
 <label for="email">Email Address</label>
 <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address"  /><br>
 <button class="clearbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">Add Partner</button>
```

Then, If you want to submit form add

```
return true;
```

or

```
return false;
```

if validation fails in checkInput function. It is better to have type submit instead of button because when user press Enter key, form will be submitted if button type is submit.

Answer (score 0):

Branching from @Roimer answer and a couple of comments, I suggest using jQuery because while also heavily simplifying your code above, gives you the awesome resource: `event.preventDefault();` which allows you to prevent the submission of the form while giving you the ability to fall back to a default submit button if javascript is not enabled or hasn't fully loaded in by the click time.

There are [other great reasons](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) to invest in this function as well.